# Keep processes running after logout

Tags: 12.04

I don't really want my brother on my computer without my permission, but I am running a Minecraft server and if I logout using Ctrl + Shift + L the server stops.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It shouldn't stop running, for you are *only* locking the screen (your are not logging out in any way).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to keep programs running after you log out.  `nohup` is an old standby and easy to use.  `screen` is useful for programs when you want to reattach to a terminal.  If your shell is `bash` you can `disown` programs that you have put in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You could also switch to another tty terminal, login and run the server from there. Then switch back to the main tty that is running the gui that your brother plays on.

```
Press ctrl + alt + F6 to switch to another tty
Press ctrl + alt + F7 to return to the primary tty
```